# Regexp [xyz] vs. [x|y|z]

Tags: regex

What is the difference between:

```
[xyz]

[x|y|z]
```

If any? Both [] and | specify alternatives.

Following code prints the exact same results:

```
String string = "the x and the y and the z and the nothing";
evaluatePattern(Pattern.compile("\\w*[xyz]\\w*"), string);
evaluatePattern(Pattern.compile("\\w*[x|y|z]\\w*"), string);
```

Comment: Well, one of them matches `"|"`.  Did you mean `/(x|y|z)/`?  On a related note, whether two REs match the same string says nothing about how equivalent the REs are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, `[x|y|z]` will match one of four characters - `x`, `y`, `z` or `|`. This is because, inside character classes (*unlike elsewhere in a regular expression*), most of the time the only "special character" is `]`, which ends the character class.

Similarly, this: `[.^$|]` will match one of five characters - `.`, `^`, `$` or `|`.

There are some "exceptions" to this rule - for example: `[^abc]` will match any single character that is **not** `a`, `b` or `c`. You can also specify a range of characters - for example, `[a-z]` matches any one lowercase letter.

It should also be noted that, for most regular expression engines, although characters like `.` don't need escaping inside character classes, a `\` is still considered to be an attempt to escape them. For example, `[\.]` matches only the character `.`, whereas `[\\.]` matches one of the characters `\` or `.`.

A more thorough explanation of character classes can be found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. In particular, note the section entitled *"Metacharacters Inside Character Classes"*.

Comment: Not quite. `^` and `-` are also special characters inside a character class (depending on their position), as well as the backslash. Therefore, your second example regex won't match a literal backslash.

Comment: Like this answer best because it points out that most other special characters are not special characters inside []. Thanks.

Comment: Tim's right, the backslash in `[\.]` would not match a literal backslash.  It's treated as an attempt to escape the dot, which (as you said) doesn't need escaping, so it's effectively ignored.  Only in the BRE and ERE flavors would the backslash be treated as a literal backslash.  The OP appears to be using Java.

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully be more correct regarding the behavior of `\` inside a character class.

Answer (score 7):

`[xyz]` matches just three characters - `x`, `y`, `z`. It's same as `(x|y|z)`

`[x|y|z]` matches 4 characters - `x`, `y`, `z`, `|`. It's same as `(x|y|z|\|)`

Note that `pipe(|)` has no special significance inside a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `[x|y|z]` will match the string `"|"`, whereas `[xyz]` will not. The brackets create a [character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx), which includes the characters `x`, `y`, `z`, and `|`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `[xyz]` is a set of the characters `x`, `y` and `z`
2. The `[x|y|z]` is the set of the characters `x`, `y` and `z` along with `|`

One of them has an extra character that it will match.

Answer (score 0):

`[xyz]` is effectively equivalent to `(?:x|y|z)`, though they may have different internal representations. The second is probably slower.  I just changed it to remove the capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, simply check [this cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) for examples of different regular expressions and rules hereof.

Hope it helps.